# Extract data from Array/Object in PHP?

Tags: php

First off, I'm new to PHP and coding in general, so this might be quite an obvious answer.

I'm currently working with the Strava API, and I'm trying to extract data from an Array/Object which is the result of the following API call:

`$recentactivities = $api->get('athlete/activities', array('per_page' => 100));`

which returns:

```
Array (
[1] => stdClass Object (
   [id] => XXXX
   [resource_state] => 2
   [external_id] => XXXX
   [upload_id] => XXXX
   [athlete] => stdClass Object (
      [id] => XXXX
      [resource_state] => 1
   )
   [name] => Let\'s see if I can remember how to do this cycling malarkey...
   [distance] => 11858.3
   [moving_time] => 1812
   [elapsed_time] => 2220
   [total_elevation_gain] => 44
   [type] => Ride
   [start_date] => 2014-07-12T13:48:17Z
   [start_date_local] => 2014-07-12T14:48:17Z
   [timezone] => (
      GMT+00:00
   ) Europe/London
   [start_latlng] => Array (
      [0] => XXXX
      [1] => XXXX
   )
   [end_latlng] => Array (
      [0] => XXXX
      [1] => -XXXX
   )
   [location_city] => XXXX
   [location_state] => England
   [location_country] => United Kingdom
   [start_latitude] => XXXX
   [start_longitude] => XXXXX
   [achievement_count] => 4
   [kudos_count] => 1
   [comment_count] => 0
   [athlete_count] => 1
   [photo_count] => 0
   [map] => stdClass Object (
      [id] => a164894160
      [summary_polyline] => XXXX
      [resource_state] => 2
   )
   [trainer] =>
   [commute] =>
   [manual] =>
   [private] =>
   [flagged] =>
   [gear_id] => b739244
   [average_speed] => 6.544
   [max_speed] => 10.8
   [average_cadence] => 55.2
   [average_temp] => 29
   [average_watts] => 99.3
   [kilojoules] => 179.9
   [device_watts] =>
   [average_heartrate] => 191.2
   [max_heartrate] => 200
   [truncated] =>
   [has_kudoed] =>
   )
```

This repeats for the most recent activities.

I'm attempting to extract `average_heartrate`, which I can do for a single object using the following:

`$recentactivities[1]->average_heartrate;`

but I'd like to extract all instances of `average_heartrate` from the Array. I've tried to use a `foreach` statement, but to be honest, I have no idea where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$averageHeartratesArray = array_map(function($value) { return $value->average_heartrate; }, $recentactivities);`

Comment: @MarkBaker A neat way, but I think that this is to complicated for a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple you can indeed use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($myArray as $obj){
  //$obj is an object so:
  if(isset($obj->average_heartrate)){
     echo $obj->average_heartrate;
  }
}
```

Comment: That works nicely. An extension to the original question, if `average_heartrate` isn't featured in the object, it returns an 'Undefined Property' notice. Could I use an IF to pass over any objects that do not feature `average_heartrate`?

Comment: Yes you can use an `if(isset())` for example. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you iterate through your array with objects and save the wanted array within an array so you can work further with it.

```
$heartrateArray = array(); // create a new array

//iterate through it with an foreach

foreach($recentactivities as $activity){

    // save the average_heartrate as a value under a new key in the array
    $heartrateArray[] = $activity->average_heartrate;
}
```